# How do you input authentication on Python Telegram script when using flask?

Tags: python, flask, telegram, telethon

I have a python script that interacts with my personal Telegram and I have a Flask script deployed that will interact with the python script. Thus, I am unable to enter a verification code when it is deployed.

This is the code within my python script:

```
client = loop.run_until_complete(
    get_connection(sfile, api_id, api_hash, phone)
)
```

Is there any possible way for me to authenticate without verification code? Else, is there any way I can key in my verification code when my Flask app has been deployed on a cloud service?

Comment: don't you think showing "get_connection" is relevant now? anyway, don't use `with TelegramClient` (equally doing `start()` without arguments), it will ask for phone from input field in interactive mode, pass `start()` the callbacks, or more properly, use `connect()` instead of `start()`, followed by `send_code_request()` and finally `sign_in()`

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve your chances or getting useful answers.

Answer (score 1):

```py
from telethon.sync import TelegramClient

# Your authentication parameters
api_id = 'YOUR_API_ID'
api_hash = 'YOUR_API_HASH'
phone_number = 'YOUR_PHONE_NUMBER'

# Path to the session file
session_file = 'session.session'

# Create a TelegramClient instance
client = TelegramClient(session_file, api_id, api_hash)

# Check if the session file exists
if not client.is_user_authorized():
    # If the session file doesn't exist, perform the initial authentication
    client.send_code_request(phone_number)
    code = input('Enter the code you received: ')

    # Complete the authentication process
    client.sign_in(phone_number, code)

# Now you can use the client for further interactions
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).